# Orbeon Forms - Buttons and Labels

Tags: button, label, orbeon

I need to add the send button twice to my form build using Orbeon Form builder; the first one should display 'Submit' and the other one should display 'Print and Submit'. But I see that the first label is getting replaced by the last one. Can some one please tell me how to add two different labels for the same button when when adding it twice to the form. This for a requirement where the form need to have two buttons. First one should submit the form to a rest service( I am using `send` button for this) and the second one should print and submit the form to rest service. Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the exact requirement is that I want to have a single button with the label 'Print and Submit' which will send the form to my rest service and also print the content of it. May be display the content on a new tab with PDF tools, just like what the `pdf` button of orbeon does. I already have a rest service that would be accepting the form; it is just I need to merge the two functions of `send` and `pdf`. Thank you.

Comment: I found out that `open-rendered-format(format = "pdf")` opens the pdf in a new tab, this would be sufficient for the first part of my requirement. So I added the below to my properties-local-prod.xml file

Comment: `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.forPrintSubmit.VIRGINAUSI.*"
   value='require-uploads
   then require-valid
   then save
   then open-rendered-format(format = "pdf")
   then save-final
   then send(uri="http://192.168.25.18:8080/RestService/rest/xml", content="xml", replace="instance")
   then navigate("http://192.168.25.18:8080/email-sent-virgin-ausi.html")
            recover navigate("http://192.168.25.18:8080/email-fail-virgin-ausi.html")'/>` .

Comment: But this doesn't give the expected out come and prompts below error Unable to Complete action There was an error running the process. Please contact the application administrator.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, you cannot put the same button twice. They have to be different buttons, which means that they have a different name. If a button is called `send` then the other one must have another name like `send-and-print`.

So create one button called `send`, the other one must be called something else. So you simply create a new button following [Button and processes](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html).

The `open-rendered-format` action is new in Orbeon Forms 2017.1. You don't say which version you are using though.

I would also properly format the process so that you can easily take out and add parts, and see which part(s) fail:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-and-print.*.*">

    require-uploads
    then require-valid
    then save
    then open-rendered-format(format = "pdf")
    then save-final
    then send(uri="http://192.168.25.18:8080/RestService/rest/xml", content="xml", replace="instance") then
    navigate("http://192.168.25.18:8080/email-sent-virgin-ausi.h‌​tml")
    recover navigate("http://192.168.25.18:8080/email-fail-virgin-ausi.h‌​tml")

</property>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I am using  2017.1.1. edition. And I have added two separate buttons. For the `send-and-print` (`forPrintSubmit` button in my code)button I need to first open the form in a new tab and then at next step want to call my webservice.  Below is how I have passed the property.

Comment: `<property as="xs:string" 
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.forPrintSubmit.VIRGINAUSI.*"
  value='require-uploads
  then require-valid
  then save
  then open-rendered-format(format = "pdf")
  then save-final
  then send(uri="http://192.168.25.15:8080/RestService/rest/xml", 
  content="xml", replace="instance")
  then navigate("http://192.168.25.15:8080/email-sent-virgin-ausi.h‌​tml")
  recover navigate("http://192.168.25.15:8080/email-fail-virgin-
  ausi.h‌tml")'/> `

Comment: And in my orbeon.log file I get the below error `|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 
|Unable to run a two-pass submission and xf:load within a same action sequence.
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException.`                          Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you so much.